# Cloud Firestore on Listening for changes, fetches an unwanted data at first call

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I'm using Cloud Firestore (not Firebase version) in Node.js and I want to listen for changes in specific collections in database. The purpose of this is to create a shared counter for statistics.

1. When the app starts, `init` is fired to populate the 'statistics' counters.
2. Then it runs a [database collection listener](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/query-data/listen#view_changes_between_snapshots), to listen for changes in firestore.

```
db.collection('cities').where('state', '==', 'CA')
  .onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
    querySnapshot.docChanges().forEach(change => {
      console.log(' FIRED ');
    });
  });
```

The unwanted behaviour is that when app is started, and there are 3 cities. It will run 3 times `' FIRED '`.

How do I avoid that behaviour ? I really just want to receive `' FIRED '` ONLY after it has been started and the new changes are made without any initial invokes.

**==== UPDATED ====**

I've added a `updatedAt` property so I could use a where clause when listening for database changes in collection, but it seems to not work properly.

Here is the code:

```
const Firestore = require('@google-cloud/firestore')
const Database = new Firestore()

const currentTime = Date.now()

Database.collection('products').where('updatedAt', '>=', currentTime ).onSnapshot(snapshot => {
  snapshot.docChanges().forEach(change => {
    console.log(' FIRED !!!', 'products', change.type)
  })
})
```

When `.where` added, no more changes captured. But if I do a simple `.get` query, it fetches the data correctly based on `.where` condition provided.

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It will run 3 times `' FIRED '`.

That's the expected behavior. When you are listening for real-time changes, it means that the first time you are calling `onSnapshot()`, you are getting all documents that correspond to that query. This means that you have to pay a number of reads that is equal to the number of documents that are returned by the query. Right after that, every time a property within a document changes, you are notified according to that change. This means that you'll have to pay only for that particular operation and nothing more.

> How do I avoid that behavior?

Unfortunately, you cannot skip the initial data and get only what's new. What you can do instead, is to add under each document a Date property and query your database on the client, according to this new property, for all documents that have changed since a previous time. I have also written an article regarding this topic called:

- [How to drastically reduce the number of reads when no documents are changed in Firestore?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-drastically-reduce-the-number-of-reads-when-no-documents-are-changed-in-firestore-8760e2f25e9e)

Comment: I will try to implement your approach and I will come back with a feedback, thank you for  explanation

Comment: Fair enough. Give it a try and tell me if it works. So keep me posted.

Comment: I'm trying to listen for a collection changes, but it doesn't work: `Database.collection(collection).where('updatedAt', '>', new Date()).onSnapshot(snapshot => ...`

But when I retrieve the docs from a collection with the same `.where` condition, it works fine. Does a Listener supports the "where" clause ?

Comment: "doesn't work" doesn't provide enough information so I can help. But yes, you can use a where call as well.

Comment: Besides that, good to hear that you tried to implement that in code. But without seeing the entire code that you using, it's hard to help. So please post a new question containing everything you have tried, using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you.

Comment: I've updated the question with the modified code based on what you've suggested. I guess I'm using a wrong date format maybe ?

Comment: Yes, most likely you don't have any products that contain in the `updatedAt` filed a value which is `>=` the current date and time, right? Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot to see it clearly.

Comment: Yeah, you were right, thank you very much Alex !

Comment: You're very welcome.